# Is there a way to add comma automatically at the end of item in json file?

Tags: python

I export a JSON file from mongodb, but it don't have comma at the end of each item, so I can't do analyze by using python, which require a comma, since I have a large number of items, is there a way to add comma automatically at the end of item in json file?

without comma

```
[
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "a"
  }
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "b"
  }
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "c"
  }
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "d"
  }
]
```

with comma

```
[
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "a"
  },
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "b"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "c"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "d"
  }
]
```

Comment: If you can read this as a string, then try str.replace('}{', '},{').    (but as mentioned by jonrsharpe, json from mongoDB should directly load into python)

Comment: _How_ are you exporting that? Right now it's not valid JSON.

Comment: If the commas aren't there, you didn't export JSON, only something that looks similar to JSON. How did you generate it?

Comment: Hi all,  I generated by using mongoexport
https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoexport/#syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data is a single **multi-line** string

```
import json

data="""[
  {
    "id" : "1",
    "name" : "a"
  }
  {
    "id" : "2",
    "name" : "b"
  }
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "c"
  }
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "d"
  }
]"""


data = data.replace('}', '},')
data_dict = json.loads(data[:-3]+']') # slice the last term

print(data_dict)
```

Output

```
[{'id': '1', 'name': 'a'}, {'id': '2', 'name': 'b'}, {'id': '3', 'name': 'c'}, {'id': '4', 'name': 'd'}]
```

For a **single** line

```
data ="""[{"id" : "1","name" : "a"}{"id" : "2","name" : "b"}{"id": "3","name": "c"}{"id": "4", "name": "d"}]"""

data = data.replace('}', '},')

import json
print(json.loads(data[:-2]+']'))
```

or more universally [see Satya's comment]

```
print(json.loads(data.replace('}{', '},{')))
```

Comment: @WCY by the way it strange that you don't get such data in the right format... I would recommend you to have a deeper look at docs of mongoDB

Comment: Hi cards, how can I remove the comma? Can you show me the code?

Comment: @WCY I remove the last comma with slice data[:-3] and then add the closing bracket ']'. This work for a string as in my example. In my example you need :-3 because there is also '\n' character to skip. In case write me again with @ cards so I will notice

Comment: in case you can also use the substitution of Satya in the 1st comment of the question

Comment: @WCY you are welcome... my mistake for the confusion!